# Hide page from navigation in SXA

Tags: sxa, best-practices

How to hide page created under 'Home' node, so that it doesn't appear in the navigation menu in SXA? For example, page like search result or error doesn't need to be included in navigation menu. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- flag your page with navigation filter
  [image]
- change navigation settings and apply a filter to it (it will not show items added to a particular filter)
  [image]

### How to create custom filter

- Navigate to `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Data/Navigation Filters`
- Create new navigation filter underneth 
  [image]

Comment: Would it be good to go ahead and add how to create a custom navigation filter.

Comment: Where is "Navigation Settings"?

Comment: @Paul `Navigation Settings` is the name of a section in Control/Rendering Properties (also referred to as "rendering parameters") dialog available for every rendering in Experience Editor

Answer (score 5):

Specify Navigation Filters for each of the Navigation renderings you use in your design i.e. "Main Navigation" and then at the page level use 'check to hide in navigation filters' option.

[image: Page Level Navigation Filters]